# PyLint not recognizing modules but code runs fine

Tags: python, pylint, neovim

I am using coc.nvim in neovim together with Pylint.

If I try to import my own module e.g. src.reverse_linked_list or an installed module like selenium, CoC displays the error message

[pylint E0401] [E] Unable to import 'xxxxx' (import-error)

double checked that **init**.py is in my directories

Running the code does not lead to any errors

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The python path need to be the same when running pylint inside neovim vs when running the code. The import using `src.reverse_linked_list` is suspicious in this regard, `src` is not generally used in the import.

Comment: I changed the folder name and tried problems.reverse_linked_list but I still have the same error

On the question of the python path, someone suggested to run
`:CocCommand python.setInterpreter`
`Select pythonPath, current: /Users/manzosk3/bin/Environments/py3_env/bin/python:`

I could be wrong but it seems to me that from the list of pythonPaths to select, it is set to the correct one (I'm using a virtual environment) but I still get the error.

Comment: Maybe a first step to identify what's wrong would be to install pylint with pip in a virtualenv and use pylint without neovim to see if it works when launched from the same directory than when you launch the python code.